# [[Ljava.lang.Integer;@3af4d6b3, [Ljava.lang.Integer;@203ba002]

Tags: java

It looks like may be a silly question but i am not being able to properly understand why this is coming every time at console. I have checked each line, but each line is responding correctly but when it comes for shuffle and then prints it gave me this output.

my code:

```
package rando;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public class random
{
    public static void main( String [] args)
    {
        Integer[][] arr = new Integer[2][2];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr[1].length; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<arr[1].length;j++)
            {
              arr[i][j] = i;
             // int iData=(int) (Math.random()*(int)arr[i][j]);
            }
        }
        Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(arr));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

Comment: I think with a multi-dimensional array, you might need to use `Arrays.deepToString()` instead of `Arrays.toString()`

Comment: What's wrong with the output?

Comment: it is giving this [[Ljava.lang.Integer;@3af4d6b3, [Ljava.lang.Integer;@203ba002] rather its should shuffle the values like : 1 3 2 0 or 3 1 2 0 any random generation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this one instead :

```
      System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));
```

Comment: ok it worked now but i found now that it printing repeating numbers   0 0 1 1 whereas with simple array it generated correct 4 numbers like 2 1 0 3 or 3 2 0 1 like wise. Any suggestions?

Comment: you are populating  0,1 values in the array `arr[i][j] = i;`

Comment: in other words not shuffling properly

Comment: nore to the point, it is doing what you are asking it to do, but not what you think you are asking it to do.  `Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(arr));` will shuffle the array, but the values in the array are also arrays.  the second level of array is not shuffled.

Comment: i corrected the logic . Now how shell i shuffle the internal array so i have to place 2 nd time Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(arr)); so that it should also shuffle the elements ???

Answer (score 2):

Here, you create an array of size two, containing two arrays of size two each:

```
Integer[][] arr = new Integer[2][2];
```

Here, you print the contents of your array:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

If you call `.toString()` on an array, you get an expression like `[[Ljava.lang.Integer;@3af4d6b3`. Since `Arrays.toString()` calls `.toString()` on every element in the array, this explains the outcome. As @JB Nizet shows, you probably meant to call `Arrays.deepToString()`.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays don't override the `toString()` method. This is why you're using `Arrays.toString()` instead of using directly `arr.toString()`. But your array contains arrays, so the `Arrays.toString()` method displays the meaningless `toString()` of every inner array that the outer array contains.

If you want a meaningful representation, loop over the array, or use `Arrays.deepToString()`, or use a List instead.